# Passing array in a function

Tags: c++, c++11

Just want to know why we sometimes declare reference(&) to the parameter accepting array in the called function because arrays are always passed by reference. So the changes in called function will reflect to the calling function parameter. It's just that no memory will be created to the called function parameter. Then why is reference taken sometimes necessarily?

```
int function1(int* arr){}

int function2(int* &arr){}

int main()
{
  int arr[5] = {0};
  function1(arr);
  function2(arr);

}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the function you're talking about?

Comment: Reference semantics are necessary if you want to modify the memory in place and avoid generating a copy. Can you show us the code you are working with.

Comment: Arrays are not always passed by reference. They are converted to a pointer who's value is the address of the first element, and carries NO INFORMATION about how many elements are in the array. The length of the array must be somehow passed (e.g. as a separate argument) or calculated by some other means.  All those are problematic since an incorrect length may be passed/calculated/assumed. Whereas a reference (or pointer) to an array means the function receives correct information about the length of the array passed - if the length is known at compile time.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Your function1() gets the address of the array *by value*, so from within function1() you can access the array, but you cannot modify that address. your function2() gets a reference to a pointer to int. In your example this does not make a difference, because arr is a const, but if you passed an actual pointer to int variable to function2(), you could modify it from within and change that pointer itself.

Comment: can you please show the declaration of the function2()?

Answer (score 0):

Because C++ supports passing by value, by reference and by pointer.

Only the good old C-style arrays automatically decay to a pointer when you pass them as a parameter, therefore you need to tell the compiler that you want to pass an object not by value but by reference.